# Unable to add background color for entire page in AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have started to build an AngularJS web app as a beginner, currently I am facing the following issue.

[image]

Below is the code in HTML file of the web app:

```
    <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>  
<body>
  <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="username" placeholder="username" required=""/>
  </div> 
  <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="password" placeholder="password" required=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
            <span class="text-danger">{{ error }}</span>
  </div>    
</body>
```

Following is the css code,

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}


html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FF9800;
  color: #000;
  font: 14px Arial;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Post your CSS to see what's going on.

Comment: html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FF9800;
 color: #000;
 font: 14px Arial;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
}

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the CSS. Read [mcve] for more information.

Comment: It looks like you're using bootstrap. If so, overwrite the white background rule under the body tag

Comment: @JulianEspinosa , can you please elaborate? thank you.

Comment: thanks all, got the solution

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS to make the `body` (and with it the background area) at least as high as the window:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FF9800;
  color: #000;
  font: 14px Arial;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="username" placeholder="username" required="" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="password" placeholder="password" required="" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
  <span class="text-danger">{{ error }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Still, iam getting the same result as above

Comment: Did you apply the background-color to `body`?

Comment: I used exactly that code in my snippet which I added, and it works as expected...

Comment: yeah, even i ran the code snippet, but the same code is not giving the expected output.

Comment: @Johannes can you share a live view of your site?

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO I think you are confusing me with the OP - I just did the snippet above, based on the code in the question and comments under the question.

Comment: @johannes yeap sorrry jajaja

Answer (score -1):

Try using the [background-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) property.

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<p>The background color grey will be applied.</p>
```